# Using Git submodules in Gitlab CI jobs dont work

Tags: gitlab, git-submodules, gitlab-ci

#### Summary

Git submodules dont work in CI jobs

#### Steps to reproduce

Create a file **.gitmodules**

```
[submodule "database_schema"]
  path = database_schema
  url = ../../nss/database_schema.git
```

My **.gitlab-ci.yml**

```
variables:
  GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY: recursive

rspec:
  stage: test
  before_script:
    - ls
    - cd database_schema
```

#### What is the current *bug* behavior?

I cant acces to my submodule repo inside ci job.

```
$ cd database_schema
/bin/bash: line 63: cd: database_schema: No such file or directory
```

But i can see the line **Upating/initializing submodules recursively.** in my job

```
Fetching changes...
Checking out e5ed3c03 as master...
Updating/initializing submodules recursively...
Checking cache for master...
Successfully extracted cache
```

Comment: Did you properly initialise the git submodule to be registered to your project?

Comment: previously, I executed `git submodule add git@url.git`

Comment: I am getting the same issue. Did you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Because ssh isn't available.

Edit each URL line in .gitmodules to use the HTTP form of the address.

The Hugo site I host has this in .gitmodules:

```
url = http://github.com/ribice/kiss.git
```

That resolved the failure during the Gitlab CI build process I was having